# How to publish react component with style?

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I want to publish a ui library using react. But I'm confuse about how to deal with styles.

For example, if I write code in a project.I will using `webpack` && `babel` to build my code, and it will create a *.css file.

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.less';

export default function() {
  return (
    <div>
      123
    </div>
  )
}
```

But, if I just write react compoents, I will use babel to compile my code.There is not `css-loader` to deail with *.less file. And after compiling, there is `requre('./index.less')` in the code, but it can't find file. So if I still want to write my code like above, how can I to publish this comonents with *.css.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into available options there are around styling components in React? Because there are a lot of options here and it comes down to what you prefer. Just a quick google search will give you many options.

My personal favorite package to use is the [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) one.